# Setting or overwriting properties of generic codable objects

Tags: json, swift, swift4, codable

Say I have a function like this:

```
private func setObject<T:Encodable>(object:T, updater:T) 
{

        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        do
        {
            let objectData = try encoder.encode(object)
            let updateData = try encoder.encode(updater)
```

Where a sample object would be:

```
public struct Something : Codable
{
    public var property1:String?
    public var property2:String?
}
```

and a a sample instance of object would be

```
object.property1 == "A"
object.property2 == "B"
```

and updater:

```
updater.property1 == "C"
updater.property2 == nil
```

Is there a quick way to create an object:

```
newObject.property1 == "C"
newObject.property2 == "B"
```

Comment: What's the question? Where does `newObject` come from?

Comment: @CodeDifferent Presumably `newObject` is the result of decoding the JSON created by the `setObject(object:updater:)` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, the generated `Something.encode(to:)` method will call `encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)` to get a container, and it will encode its properties into that container. So you need to make both `object` and `update` use the same container to encode themselves. Then maybe `update`'s properties will overwrite `object`'s properties. On the other hand, maybe the encoder will throw an error. Let's try it and see.

To make them use the same container, we'll create a wrapper type that holds the object and the update.

```
import Foundation

public struct Something : Codable
{
    public var property1:String?
    public var property2:String?
}

struct UpdateWrapper {
    var something: Something
    var update: Something
}
```

Now we will make `UpdateWrapper` conform to `Encodable`. If we let the compiler generate the conformance, it will look like this:

```
// What the compiler would generate, but NOT what we want.

extension UpdateWrapper: Encodable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case something
        case update
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(something, forKey: .something)
        try container.encode(update, forKey: .update)
    }

}
```

The reason we don't want this is because this will result in `something` and `update` getting separate containers from the encoder, and we want them to go into the same container. So instead we'll conform to `Encodable` like this:

```
extension UpdateWrapper: Encodable {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        try something.encode(to: encoder)
        try update.encode(to: encoder)
    }
}
```

In this way, `something` and `encoder` each receive the same `Encoder`, with the same `codingPath`, so they get the same container from the encoder. We can test it like this:

```
let original = Something(property1: "A", property2: "B")
let update = Something(property1: "C", property2: nil)

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let jsonData = try! encoder.encode(UpdateWrapper(something: original, update: update))
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
print("jsonString=\(jsonString)")

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let reconstructed = try! decoder.decode(Something.self, from: jsonData)
print("reconstructed=\(reconstructed)")
```

Here's the output:

```
jsonString={"property2":"B","property1":"C"}
reconstructed=Something(property1: Optional("C"), property2: Optional("B"))
```

So it does work. Is it a good idea? I don't know. I'm not sure it's specified anywhere that you're actually **allowed** to encode with the same key into the same container twice.

Comment: This is excellent thanks! I am using the UpdateWrapper with generic classes and it works just as great

Answer (score 0):

Constraining to `Encodable` doesn't give enough information. You can create a separate protocol to update objects.

```
protocol Updatable {
    func update(_ updatedObject: Self) -> Self
}

public struct Something: Updatable {
    var property1: String?
    var property2: String?

    func update(_ updatedObject: Something) -> Something {
        return Something(
            property1: updatedObject.property1 ?? property1,
            property2: updatedObject.property2 ?? property2)
    }
}

func setObject<T: Updatable>(object: T, updater: T) -> T {
    return object.update(updater)
}
```